# Errors in IE8 for site using Backbone.js w/ Require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, internet-explorer-8, requirejs

I'm getting the following errors coming back in IE8:

> Message: Object expected  Line: 27  Char: 1  Code: 0  URI:
>   http://cdn.example.com/images/example4/js/libs/jquery.backgroundSize.js
>
> Message: '$.fn' is null or not an object  Line: 8  Char: 1  Code: 0 
>   URI:
>   http://cdn.example.com/images/example4/js/libs/jquery.waitUntilExists.js
>
> Message: 'fn' is null or not an object  Line: 62  Char: 73  Code: 0 
>   URI:
>   http://cdn.example.com/images/example4/js/libs/jquery.nicescroll.js
>
> Message: Object expected  Line: 34  Char: 231  Code: 0  URI:
>   http://cdn.example.com/images/example4/js/libs/backbone.js
>
> Message: 'Vent' is null or not an object  Line: 19  Char: 3  Code: 0 
>   URI: http://cdn.example.com/images/example4/js/models/auth.js

Our site is a SPA built with Backbone.js and Require.js for dependency management. This problem only shows up on IE8 (and possibly earlier versions). Each of these files, with the exception of the last which is caused because 'Vent' extends Backbone.Event, are all created as shims for Backbone.js in our Require.js config file.

Require.js config:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'http://cdn.staging.example.com/images/example4/js',
    paths: {
        underscore: './libs/underscore',
        jquery: './libs/jquery',
        backbone: './libs/backbone',
        example: './libs/example',
        blockui: './libs/jquery.blockUI',
        backgroundsize: './libs/jquery.backgroundSize',
        nicescroll: './libs/jquery.nicescroll',
        waituntilexists: './libs/jquery.waitUntilExists',
        swfobject: './libs/swfobject',
        spinner: './libs/jquery.spinner'
    },
    //Create shims for Backbone
    shim: {
        'backgroundsize': {
            deps: [ 'jquery'],
            exports: 'backgroundsize'
        },
        'nicescroll': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'nicescroll'
        },
        'waituntilexists': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'waituntilexists'
        },
        'spinner': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'spinner'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: [ 'underscore', 'jquery','blockui','backgroundsize','nicescroll', 'waituntilexists', 'swfobject', 'spinner'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});

requirejs(['app'],
    function(App){
        App.initialize();
    });
```

Any suggestions as what would be causing this, we're using Backbone.js 0.9.2 and Require.js 2.0.6.

Comment: 1 idea: can you confirm that jquery is being downloaded? (It looks like it's missing given the errors).

Comment: Where's the 'app' path defined unless it's your /root/app?

Comment: From what I've seen jQuery is being loaded. And yes it is the root app.

Comment: Why do you have "relative" paths? isn't libs/ actually inside js/? I have a small example using jQuery, Backbone, Bootstrap and a Backbone plugin called Backbone-Super and it loads without problems on IE; the trick I am doing is define a "backbone" module with all the backbone dependencies so I do not have to keep asking for them every time I need to use Backbone. https://github.com/erickrdch/backbone-require/tree/master/public

Comment: This issue was actually related to a bad file that some how got put out at one point. Some users had that file cached. Clearing the cache corrected the problem. I appreciate everyone's answers and suggestions. I'll look at implementing some of them and see how they work out for performance.

Answer (score 0):

IE has some issues with shims as you can read here http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#nodefine

As far as I understand from http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

> Only use other "shim" modules as dependencies for shimmed scripts, or AMD libraries that have no dependencies and call define() after they also create a global (like jQuery or lodash). Otherwise, if you use an AMD module as a dependency for a shim config module, after a build, that AMD module may not be evaluated until after the shimmed code in the build executes, and an error will occur. The ultimate fix is to upgrade all the shimmed code to have optional AMD define() calls.

There could be an issue with having jquery as a dependency of a shim or jquery was not loaded so it couldnt set it's global.

Comment: Looking into the links and information you provided. Will let everyone know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding backbone to your main require like this:

```
    requirejs(['app', 'backbone'], function(App){ App.initialize(); });
```

Also, try to use r.js to generate one concatenated file (make sure you turn off optimization) and you can see the order in which require is loading scripts.